# How can I write a Dataframe into Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

My Dataframe `df` looks like

```
[Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
```

I creating a Kafka Sink for streaming queries, but I received nothing from kafka. why?

```
ds = df \
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .writeStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
  .option("topic", "topic1") \
  .start()
```

Comment: df is a normal dataframe,just like [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]. I want to receive the content of this dataframe from Kafka. The type of this content can be json. The problem is that I don’t know how to convert the dataframe into json and write it into Kafka.

Answer (score 2):

You will not receive anything from Kafka because based on your code you are trying to select the columns `key` and `value` from a Dataframe which has only columns `age` and `name`. You need to select those as shown below.

Also, you do not need `writeStream` if your Dataframe is static. In that case you need to apply `write` and `save`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct, to_json}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("myAppName")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  // create DataFrame
  import spark.implicits._
  val df = Seq((3, "Alice"), (5, "Bob")).toDF("age", "name")
  df.show(false)

  // +---+-----+
  // |age|name |
  // +---+-----+
  // |3  |Alice|
  // |5  |Bob  |
  // +---+-----+

  // write to Kafka as is with "age" as key and "name" as value
  df.selectExpr("CAST(age AS STRING) as key", "CAST(name AS STRING) as value")
    .write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("topic", "test-topic")
    .save()
```

If you want to store your data into a json string you can apply the following"

```scala
  // convert columns into json string
  val df2 = df.select(col("name"),to_json(struct($"*"))).toDF("key", "value")
  df2.show(false)

  // +-----+------------------------+
  // |key  |value                   |
  // +-----+------------------------+
  // |Alice|{"age":3,"name":"Alice"}|
  // |Bob  |{"age":5,"name":"Bob"}  |
  // +-----+------------------------+
```